# Hibernate generates extra left join with many to one association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple Hibernate `@ManyToOne` mapping between two entities, using an association table thanks to annotation `@JoinTable`.
Here is my mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    private Long id;
    private Address address;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(
            name = "customer_address_association",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    )
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Address {

    private Long id;
    private String street;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
}
```

When I query on Customer entity, I always get an extra left join to the join table. For example, a HQL query such as `SELECT c.id from Customer c` generates the following SQL query: `select customer0_.id as col_0_0_ from customer customer0_ left outer join customer_address_association customer0_1_ on customer0_.id=customer0_1_.customer_id`.

Full source code to reproduce is available here: https://github.com/ndionisi/hibernate-extra-left-join

I reproduce it with Hibernate 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3. Is there any way to prevent Hibernate from generating the left join to `customer_address_association` table? It impacts the performance on large tables.

Comment: How would it know if the customer has an address or not (and thus if address must be null or not) without that left join? Use a join column instead of a join table, and there won't be any left join anymore.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense when I load the full Customer entity, but I'm surprised to see the left join also when I'm not loading the full entity, e.g `SELECT c.id from Customer c`

Comment: Oh yes, missed that. You should report the issue to Hibernate

Comment: Just created it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12895. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `FetchType.LAZY` on the `@ManyToOne` annotation.